# Supremum and infimum of a given set without using limits or differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I need to find the supremum and infimum of the following set:
$$\Big\{ y \in \mathbb{R} \Big| y = x + |x - 1| \text{ for some } x \in \mathbb{R}\Big\}$$

I'm unable to use limits or differentiation for questions like this one and I'm unsure of what to do in order to solve it. If anyone is able to help me I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

By inspection of the equation I know when $x$ is really large and positive that there's not going to be a supremum, and when $x$ is large and negative it's going to tend towards 0. But I'm not really sure how to show this without taking limits and I'm a bit unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the (continuous) function $x \mapsto x+|x-1|$??

Comment: What is $|x - 1|$ when $x < 1$? Answer: $1 - x$, so what is x + |x - 1|$ in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two separate cases. The first is $x \ge 1$ and the second is $x <1$.

If $x \ge 1$, then
$$y=x + |x-1| = x+x-1 = 2x-1$$
Clearly this has no upper bound, while the lower bound is $y=1$ (when $x=1$).

If $x<1$, then
$$y=x + |x-1| = x-x+1 = 1$$

In other words your set is
$$\left\{ y \in \Bbb R | y \ge 1\right\}$$
which is the interval $[1, + \infty )$.